# How to solve SMTP Connection timeout Exception in AWS Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: java, spring-boot, amazon-ec2, smtp, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have deployed springboot java jar in EC2 instance using Elastic Beanstalk. The api in jar after adding user to DB sents a confirmation mail. This functionality working fine in localhost, however on aws instance , i am getting gatway timeout 504.

Here is setting of SMTP server (It is smart server which dont use username , password also  I have added the public ip address of my EC2 insctance in the server)
*Java SMTP Settings :*

```
String host = "212.48.*.*";
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.trust", "false");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "false");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "false");
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "25");
Session session = Session.getInstance(props);
            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                    InternetAddress.parse(receiverMail));

                     Transport.send(message);
```

=====================================================
*Error Message:*
2020-04-13 20:56:45.521 ERROR 5887 --- [nio-5000-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: **Couldn't connect to host, port: 212.48.**.***, 25; timeout -1;
  nested exception is:
        java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)] with root cause**

java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:607) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:556) ~[na:1.8.0_232]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like AWSEC2 instance dont allow external SMTP server, I have solved this issue by verifing domin in AWS SES and using SMTP settings.